# GCP instance ssh doesn't recognize user anymore because of different case

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-compute-engine

Since last week, I've been unable to ssh into my instances on compute engine, either from the command line or the gcp console.

I get the following message:

```
(gcloud.compute.ssh) User [kxxgxxx@gmail.com] does not have permission to access users instance [kxxgxxx@gmail.com] (or it may not exist): End user credentials must match the user specified in the request. Request for user [ kxxgxxx@gmail.com] does not match the credential for [KxxGxxx@gmail.com].
```

Originally, my email had uppercase letter (KxxGxxx@gmail.com). But when I log in on gcp, my email is lowercased.
Never had any issue with about a week ago.
Now I can't log in. I can log in from other accounts but can't reach this one. Some processes are running from this account so I need to be able to mange it again.

Thanks for reading and helping!

I tried to log log out and log in but it didn't change anything.
I tried to log in from a different account. That works.

EDIT :

I use the following command to ssh:
`gcloud compute ssh <instance-name>`

Comment: I don't know the answer but another post has similar problems. Looks like something has changed in GCP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894668/what-causes-gcp-iam-to-auto-capitalize-the-username-email

Comment: You can use the `sudo -u <USERNAME> /bin/bash` to switch identities to the problem username once logged in using a different user.

Comment: What is the command line that you are using and the exact error message? Add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes I got the same issue!
I edited the question with the command line
I also tried to sudo but I couldn't switch user. Maybe I'm not typing the user correctly but I get

`sudo: unknown user: kxxgxxx_gmail_com`
`sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Comment: List the home directory to check for the users: `ls -l /home`. I will guess that you will find that the user's home directory and username have uppercase characters. I have not verified this, but you should be able to rename the directory to be all lowercase. Then check the list of users for the exact spelling and case: `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`.

Comment: Thanks for the info
I didn't manage to log in as a different the users, but it seems they solved the issue with the last update.
I can log in again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue has resolved itself. Maybe with the last gcloud update.